# \documentclass - {paper} vs. {memoir}

Tags: memoir, document-classes, paper

Let me profess that I know that I have made some bad choices. Hopefully I can get some help here, to clear things up. I have been told and read that writing an article/paper should in most cases be done in the document class `memoir`, for being the most flexible and with the most tools.

Now... I found this great template, which is written in the documentclass `paper`, which looked liked it only needed very few adjustments, to be really useful for my purpose, which I hope to use and share as a template at my faculty. Unfortunately I can't find any guide or notes about the documentclass `paper`, which is why I'm here to get help.

The preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{paper} 
\usepackage{lipsum, babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\usepackage{usebib}
\bibinput{bibliography}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{VERY LONG TITLE}
\subtitle{The subtitle\\
\hfill\includegraphics[height=3cm]{frog.jpg} %logo
\vspace{-3cm}}
\author{First Name (A) Last Name (A)\footnote{E-mail: A@university.com}\\
First Name (B) Last Name (B)\footnote{E-mail: B@university.com}}
\institution{Name of University}
```

Which produces something like this:

[image]

My first question is, why isn't the footnote for the authors e-mail showing up at the bottom of the page? (And how to fix this)

My second question is related to `\checkandfixthelayout` in `memoir`. Is there something similar for `paper` or is there another way to fix words exceeding the margin, as shown here:

[image]

So my big question is, if it's easier to make these few adjustments in `paper`, or to switch to memoir and build a similar setup? (and if so, how to do it.)

EDIT:
Added the \usepackage{microtype} to the preamble, which has fixed the problem with the margin.

Comment: You found a template named `paper`? Where?

Comment: Use `\thanks` instead of `\footnote` in the `\author` field to get the emails displayed at the bottom. As for the fix with words exceeding the margin, I'd recommend using the package `microtype`, at least as a first measure.

Comment: Regarding tho `\checkandfixthelayout` option, did you try to load the package `microtype`? I.e. simply add `\usepackage{microtype}` to your preamble.

Comment: I used the `\usepackage{microtype}`, and the margin is now straight. I also tried `\thanks`, but it didn't change anything. No added footnotes or lines at the bottom of the page to show e-mails or other information.

Comment: i've just done a ctan search for anything named "paper", and the only plausible offering is a documentclass based on `article`, which bears absolutely no similarity to what you show.  so we really do need to learn where you found this package before we can make any intelligent suggestions.

Comment: please hare with us where we can find the template.

Comment: Asking what is better, using  `memoir` or using `paper` is a question very hard to answer. It is like asking which religion is better than another. You can savely try out both and decide which one fits you better. You also don't have to stick with your decision, you can later convert to another class ;-)

Comment: I'm looking through my browsing history. Currently I'm using the site "Overleaf" to collaborate with others using LaTeX and thought I might have used one of their templates from the site. Unfortunately it doesn't look like, it's where I got it from. I've looked through 15 pages of templates, and I can't find it on the site.

Comment: @Johannes_B `... don't have to stick with your decision, you can later convert to another class ...`. Perhaps the analogy with religions is not an altogether ideal choice? ;)

Comment: Note that `\checkandfixthelayout` has nothing to do with the problem of words running into the margins. It has to do with where the margins go in the first place, true, but difficulties with line-breaking aren't addressed by `\checkandfixthelayout`.

Comment: Don't use `utf8x`. Are you sure you and your colleagues will all get the correct variety of English? It is recommended to specify the particular variant. Don't use explicit mark-up, including uppercase in the arguments to commands such as `\title`, `subtitle` etc. (`\author` may be an exception depending on the class, which we don't have access to.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceeding phrases over the margins can be fixed manually by either rephrasing or telling latex to individually hyphenate words `con\-sti\-tu\-tion` for example creates points to hyphenate.

Another method is to use the package `\usepackage{microtype}` to make microadjustments to your document. It changes things like interletter spaces etc. Usually the default settings might be enough (I used it for easing the bibliography that went over the margins in my phd). However, more indepth adjustments can be made, some of which change the face of your document however -- so you have to decide if you can live with that.