# My latex file is not working: document class not found

Tags: errors, packages, paper

I am trying to run my latex file. I am getting the following error. I think it is something related to the document class. We create it "paper" and we put it in the same file. However, it is stated that it is not found. 
This is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{Paper}
\usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{paralist}
  \usepackage{graphics}
  \usepackage{epsfig} 
 \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red}

  \textheight=8.2 true in
   \textwidth=5.0 true in
    \topmargin 30pt
     \setcounter{page}{1}

\def\proofb{\par{\it Proof} \ignorespaces}

\def\endproofb{\hfill$\Box$}



\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{main}{Main Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\eps}[1]{{#1}_{\varepsilon}}


\title[]{}


\author[]{}


 \keywords{}



\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

This is the message error:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ArticleSC".tex

Unfortunately, the package symbol could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\SAMARA\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Unfortunately, the package symbol could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\SAMARA\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\SAMARA\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Couldn't open `ps.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\SAMARA\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\SAMARA\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ArticleSC".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Sorry, but as long as you so not provide any code, we have no ide what you are yoing wrong.

Comment: And, welcome to TeX.SE. For more information how to create a MWE, please see: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that.

Comment: Okay, I will add the code.

Comment: The error messages refer to the log files (`pdflatex.log` and `miktex-maketfm.log`, the path where these files can be found is also specified in the error message). These files contain more information on the errors. Could you add the contents of these files to your question?

Comment: So, as you can see I am trying to write a paper. So, I introduced a paper class "paper". The thing is that it is working on my supervisor's laptop but not on mine.

Comment: The thing is that I am not using a well know package. I am creating one and I am calling it "Paper" (its type is a Latex class ) and when I am calling it in the code, latex is not identifying it.

Comment: Then let us see the code for `Paper.cls`? But I have to ask, if you hardly know anything about LaTeX and LaTeX debugging why are you developing your own class?

Comment: My supervisor created it and sent it to me. It is working on his laptop but not on mine.

Comment: There is no package called `symbol` in the CTAN archive (and it's a silly name for a package anyway, considering how many different symbol fonts etc are available in LaTeX). Presumably this is something else that your supervisor wrote.

Comment: So why it is working on his laptop?

Comment: @samarachamoun you could ask your supervisor if he has a file `symbol.sty` or `symbol.tex` (maybe a collection of macros for symbols that he created for personal use). If that is the case then you can copy those files to the folder on your own computer where your `ArticleSC.tex` file is, that might solve your current issue. Also note that LaTeX can be case-sensitive, if you use `\documentclass{Paper}` then the file must be called `Paper.cls` and not `paper.cls`, and the same for `\usepackage`, `\input` etc. (I'm not saying you do this wrong but note that this could be an issue).

Comment: Thank you for your help. By the way, now I tried to run the new class that he created it "Paper" on my laptop. It is mentioned that Log file not found.

Comment: unrelated but use `\usepackage{graphicx}` not `\usepackage{graphics}\usepackage{epsfig} `

Answer (score 1):

Based on the possibility it is just you forcing the capital P that cause a problem with that class, I have amended the rest of your MWE, including comments where problems arose (may arise later).

[image]

```
    \\documentclass[a4paper]{paper} %do not use P = LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `Paper', but the document class provides `paper'.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     % for * theorem environments
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{microtype} % recommended for anti-hyphen microadjustments  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294478
%\usepackage{graphics} % graphicx is preferred
%\usepackage{epsfig}    % graphicx is preferred
\usepackage{graphicx}   % prefered to include epsfig's and others
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red}
\usepackage{bookmark} % recommended by TeX but clashes if placed before Hyperref
  \textheight=8.2 true in
   \textwidth=5.0 true in
    \topmargin 30pt
     \setcounter{page}{1}

\def\proofb{\par{\it Proof} \ignorespaces}

\def\endproofb{\hfill$\Box$}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{main}{Main Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{Example}{Example}[section] % CLASH WARNING 2nd definition of example see caution below
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\eps}[1]{{#1}_{\varepsilon}}

\title{ArticleSC}
\subtitle{The longer subtitle}
\author{Samara Chamoun \small (E-mail: LbAm@university.com) % remove following % for second line
%\and First Prof (B) Last Prof (B) \small(E-mail: B@university.com)
}
\institution{e.g. University of life}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{parbox}{0.6\textwidth}%
\maketitle
\end{parbox}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{ctan_lion_350x350.png}
\end{minipage}
\hrule
\abstract
\keywords{key clef treble bass $\ep$ \LaTeX} %read the manual this is not correct way
\hrule\smalltableofcontents\vspace{12pt}\hrule

\section{Introduction}

Wello Horld\footnote{Well Hello} here I will add a \remark (By others)``From a logical point of view, there is no difference between a lemma, proposition, theorem, or corollary - they are all claims waiting to be proved. However, we use these terms to suggest different levels of importance and difficulty.''

\notation Ano Tation without a number.

\definition - a precise and unambiguous description of the meaning of a mathematical term.  It characterizes the meaning of a word by giving all the properties and only those properties that must be true.
\theorem - a mathematical statement that is proved using rigorous mathematical reasoning.  In a mathematical paper, the term theorem is often reserved for the most important results.
\lemma - a minor result whose sole purpose is to help in proving a theorem.  It is a stepping stone on the path to proving a theorem. Very occasionally lemmas can take on a life of their own (Zorn’s lemma, Urysohn’s lemma, Burnside’s lemma, Sperner’s lemma).
%\limon - a cidic fruit whose sole purpose is to test if your looking.
\corollary - a result in which the (usually short) proof relies heavily on a given theorem (we often say that “this is a corollary of Theorem A”).
\proposition - a proved and often interesting result, but generally less important than a theorem.
\conjecture - a statement that is unproved, but is believed to be true (Collatz conjecture, Goldbach conjecture, twin prime conjecture).

\Example Here we are using Example with a capital $E=mc^2$
\example CAUTION \textbackslash example is a fixed definition \item generating lines fit for \item providing a list \end{list}

\end{document}
```